# Sharing on React JS Mobile application

Tags: android, reactjs, web-share

I am trying to get my application to allow sharing to other apps but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using React JS and have tried to use the following code

```
        // Check if navigator.share is supported by the browser
        if (navigator.share) {
            console.log("Congrats! Your browser supports Web Share API");
            navigator
                .share({
                    url: "https://www.google.com",
                    text: "add text",
                    title: "Your Discovery",
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Sharing successfull");
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    console.log("Sharing failed");
                });
        } else {
            console.log("Sorry! Your browser does not support Web Share API");
        }
    };
```

I gathered this wouldn't work on my application as its not a supported browser type. But was wondering if it would work if I launched an in app browser through my application?

Or does anyone know how to add native sharing capabilities to a react js application.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try that in a real device browser ( smart phone )? 
I guess this should work in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem! My app is built using ionic and react js and this was the only solution that worked on native devices.

```
 import { Share } from '@capacitor/share';
    
    const [basicShare, setBasicShare] = useState(false)
    
    
    useEffect(() => () => {
            if (basicShare) {
                Share.share({
                    title: 'Title',
                    text: 'enter text',
                    url: "https://google.com",
                    dialogTitle: 'Share',
                });
            }
            setBasicShare(false)
    
        },
            [basicShare]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is supported only on a few browsers. Even if you use a browser component the app will try to open the default browser which may not support this feature. Below is the browser compatibility for this feature. Android and iPhone may work as it has support.

[image]